# How to look up in a cell of Strings for existence of a specific string

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a cell like

```
A = {'erogol' 'grerol' 'biral'}
```

then I want to search inside for a particular string.

Is there any special function doing it?

Comment: May I ask how did you come up with these strings? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the functions is `strmatch`:

```
    index = strmatch('grerol',A,'exact');
```

It returns an array of indexes. It is now deprecated, and Mathworks recommend using `strcmp` instead

```
    logicalIndexing = strcmp('grerol',A);
```

---

Another option is `ismember` :

```
    [bIsMember,index]=ismember('grerol',A);
```

---

Another option is `strfind` :
        indexes =  strfind(A,'grerol');

---

Last but not least,

```
    booleanIndexes = cellfun(@(x)(isequal(x,'grerol')),A);
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you could also add `strfind` to the list. (+1 anyway).